# Blended lines do not look as expected

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I use the following fragment shader, which uses the fog effect, to draw my scene:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform int EnableFog;
uniform float FogMinDist;
uniform float FogMaxDist;

varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;
varying float EyeToVertexDist;

float computeFogFactor()
{
    float fogFactor = 1.0;

    if (EnableFog != 0)
    {
        //Use a bit lower vlaue of FogMaxDist to get a better fog effect - it will make the far end disappear quicker. 
        float fogMaxDistABitCloser = FogMaxDist * 0.98;

        fogFactor = (fogMaxDistABitCloser - EyeToVertexDist) / (fogMaxDistABitCloser - FogMinDist);

        fogFactor = clamp(fogFactor, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    return fogFactor;
}

void main(void)
{
    float fogFactor = computeFogFactor();

    gl_FragColor = DestinationColor * fogFactor;
}
```

And i enable alpha blending:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The result is the following scene:

[image]

My problem is with the places in which the lines overlap - the result is that the color seems darker than the color of both lines:

[image]

How i can fix it?

Comment: That is because of the way color blending works. You draw one line, then draw another on top of it, and so on. The end result is that the pixels add up in the framebuffer, making the intersections look darker. If you tweak your blend function, I think you might be able to fix it. I'm not very versed on color blending myself, so I'd suggest you give it a try to some of the available combos: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

As already described in the comment you are blending the newly drawn line with the background which may already contain colours from another object at certain pixels, in your case where lines overlap. To solve this you will either have to draw your lines without overlapping or make your drawing independent from the current buffer state.

In your specific case you may pass the background colour to your fragment shader via some uniform or even a texture and then do your blending manually in the fragment shader.

In general you might want to draw the grid to some frame buffer object (FBO) with attached texture and then draw the whole texture in a single draw call using your fog shader and blending. The drawing to FBO should then be with disabled blending.

There are other ways such as drawing the grid to a stencil buffer first and then redraw a full-screen rect applying a colour with your shader and blending.